# Generating Certificates for Windows Azure

Tags: java, azure, certificate

I would like to generate a certificate, public key, private key and all other things needed in order to connect Windows Azure via java code. I prefer using only keytool.
How do I do that?

The java code requires a JKS file with private key in it.

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Keytool can help you up to certain extent however combination of Keytool and OpenSSL will give you everything you need to have your Java based application connect to Windows Azure (both management portal as well as SSL enabled Web Application.

Please follow the documentation as [Migrating Keys from 'keytool' to 'OpenSSL'](http://www.herongyang.com/crypto/Migrating_Keys_keytool_to_OpenSSL.html)

1. Using "keytool" to generate a private and public key pair.
2. Using "keytool" to export the self-signed certificate from PrivateKeyEntry.
3. Using "keytool" to display details of a certificate.
4. Using "OpenSSL" to view certificate exported by "keytool".
5. Writing "DumpKey.java" to dump key pair out of "keytool" keystore files.
6. Using "OpenSSL" to convert dumped key pair from binary to Base64 encoding.
7. Using "OpenSSL" to view key pair dumped and converted from "keytool" keystore files.